# Cocos2d-X how to change Android minSDKVersion

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have created my cocos2d-X application using the create android script. I now want to lower the min sdk version in the Android Manifest, but that gives me an error t

```
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-14 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in ./AndroidManifest.xml
```

How do i fix this ? Will i have to create a new project with lower SDK Version ?

Kind Regards,
Muhammad Mateen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change in Cocos2d-x in Application.mk file
Like this

> APP_PLATFORM := android-9